# Where is the android app private key stored?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I am in an unfortunate situation of having to update a Phonegap that was published 3 years ago and both devs that worked on it are long gone.

I have successfully deployed the app to a few Android devices and I am ready to redeploy it to the Google Play Store.

I am ready to build a release version of the app but I am unable to locate the apps private key. Google makes it very clear that you need the same key when deploying an update to the app.

Is this stored somewhere on the google developer console or inside the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the private key is not stored online!

It wouldn't be private then.

If you don't have the key anymore you wont be able to update your app.

Note: if you just lost the password, there is a way:
https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/

Comment: Damn! So unless I can get in touch with the original developers is my only choice is to generate a new private key and have the app deploy as an entirely new app on the Play Store?

Comment: Yep, either you get the keystore, or you deplay a new app with a new package name

Comment: Actually, is there a chance that it is stored within the applications source?

Comment: Could be, but normaly you won't store it there because that is insecure.

Comment: I was able to locate a android-cert-pass file in the old employees shared files but am I able to obtain the .keystore file using only the password?

Comment: I am not sure what `android-cert-pass` is, if it is the keyfile you can use the tool I mentioned to get the password. But only using the password it is impossible to get the file.